# php generated content cant call java script functions

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am generating this php code and want to call a JavaScript function from it.

This code is not able to call this javascript function.

```
<?php
    echo '<li><div class="product"><a onclick="showCustomer("brand","puma")"><i class="icon-remove"></i>Shoes</a></div></li>';
?>
```

I have a showCustomer() function which works perfectly when called from normal html components.
Is there anyway i can do this?

Comment: Double check those quotes. Or just query the DOM and add the event _in JavaScript_.

Comment: Your code `showCustomer()` will only fire if you press the button. You can do this though to fire the function: `<script>showCustomer("brand","puma");</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using single quotes in the onclick:

```
<?php echo '<li><div class="product"><a onclick="showCustomer(\'brand\',\'puma\')"><i class="icon-remove"></i>Shoes</a></div></li>' ;?>
```

You probably will see a syntax error in the console

Answer (score 2):

Look at your rendered HTML:

```
<li><div class="product"><a onclick="showCustomer("brand","puma")">...
```

Does that look right to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo '<li><div class="product"><a onclick="showCustomer(\'brand\',\'puma\')"><i class="icon-remove"></i>Shoes</a></div></li>' ;?>
```

should do.